# how can we integrate two rails applications deployed within an intranet

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest

- Is RESTful services the only route for integrating any application with a rails applications including any other rails applications irrespective of whether it is in same network or not?
- For integrating two applications how heavy is a RESTful service compared to the RMI based integration available in other technologies like Java EE?
- Is there way to integrate two rails applications using any natively understood binary format which can avoid transformation to a different format ex: HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST approach means simply that application A will make requests of application B (and potentially the other way around) using the HTTP protocol.  The data send can be in whatever format you like, although JSON is the default today (and XML was the default yesterday, and even ... SOAP -- gaq!).

These days, the vast majority of external APIs are implemented this way -- Amazon, Google Maps, Yelp, etc, etc, etc.  Why?  Because the HTTP (or HTTPS) protocol is well understood and widely deployed.  No special configuration is required and the same protocol that serves the application to regular people on web browsers works for other applications.  Rails makes this brilliantly easy (if you go with the flow).

Java's RMI is a specific protocol (just as HTTP is).  The advantage is that objects defined in A are available as instances in B (after a great deal of work in both).  This really makes sense when you have a set of applications all designed up front to work together and whose main requirement is to be distributed across locations, servers, etc.  RMI creates a tight binding between applications -- a change in one typically requires a change in the other.  It's right for some kinds of applications.

But if you have, for example, two departments in a company who talk to each other, but don't want to be "bound at the hip", a REST interface provides a great deal of flexibility.

Your second question ("how heavy") is very difficult to answer.  A company I worked for in 2001 had hundreds of servers all running an instance of a "worker" process -- they were all designed to queue their results to a "controller" process which would process the output and forward to another set servers designed to process and manage the data.  In 2001, this was the right architecture because it was completely designed to work together -- persistent socket connections on a single subnet of our intranet running on a room full of servers.  Now in 2012, that room full of servers is replaced by a few high-powered processors running 64-bit OS and addressing massive amounts of memory -- it's a whole new world.  A doubling of performance in 2001 could save potentially millions of dollars of hardware, operational support, space and so on.  In 2012, the most expensive thing is good developers!  So "heavy" is really kind of irrelevant in all but the most compute-intensive operations these days.  An HTTP request is light and simple.

Final question: natively understood binary format.  Sure, if needed.  In the end, any binary format that is sent over the wire between two servers needs to be serialized and de-serialized as a stream, and this is work, both for programmers and for machines.  JSON is a text format, but one natively understood by JavaScript (JavaScript Object Notation) and has the distinct advantage of being human-readable.  Given that most servers are set up to compress output automatically whether something is text or binary becomes kind of less relevant, at least as far as I/O and payload goes.  Of course you *can* come up with any mutually understood format and send it over HTTP, but again, this is something that mattered a decade ago, and today is usually not an issue worth considering.  Processors have been getting faster and faster, and memory cheaper (and bigger) -- so (as always) I/O (whether network or disk) is the typical bottleneck in modern applications.

If I were to re-design the application I mentioned from 2001 where hundreds of (today's) servers needed to communicate with (many) peer servers very specifically designed to interoperate, I might work to make sure that the serialize/deserialize process was as lightweight as possible (but only *if* it turned out to be a bottleneck).  For me, being bound to any given platform or language is a non-starter -- the computing world is moving way to fast.

But in almost all realistic business applications today, keeping things simple, standard, and straightforward has both present and future benefits that make the need to worry obsessively about performance a thing of the past.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: brilliant write-up. Thanks. I have heard of some of the reasons that you mentioned here, before.